# how to get the int value from this $68.95

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer

[image: this is the dataframe,how to get just the value from the price column]

i tried

```
int(df3.iloc[:,0:1].split('\'')[1])
```

it says that

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'.
```

i m new with pandas

Comment: What exactly should the result be?

Comment: from $68.95 to just 68.95 ,which should be an integer value

Comment: `68.95` is not an integer...

Comment: ops ,i should said just 68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you would like to do this for every row in the price column and not just the first (zero-index) row? There is more than one way to skin a cat in pandas, but this will do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_numeric(df3['price'].str.lstrip('$')).astype(int)
```

**Let's break this down according to how it's evaluated:**

`df3['price']` returns a series object:

```
0     $68.95
1    $157.49
Name: price, dtype: object
```

`.str.lstrip('$')` calls the string processing `lstrip` method on every item in that series, thereby returning a new series with the dollar signs removed:

```
0     68.95
1    157.49
Name: price, dtype: object
```

Pass that new series to `pd.to_numeric()` which returns yet another new series with all the strings converted to float64:

```
0     68.95
1    157.49
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

And finally `.astype(int)` calls the `astype` method of that last series and casts it as an int32 dtype.

```
0     68
1    157
Name: price, dtype: int32
```

Comment: u gave a me a clear view about this . thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pandas.to_numeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) or [DataFrame.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Answer (score 0):

You say in the comments you want 68.95 as an integer. that is not possible. you can get 68 as an integer with

```
int(float(df.iloc[0,0].split('$')[1]))
```

Or as an float of 68.95 by not doing the conversion to int after the float conversion

Comment: corrected!! in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

Get the numeric portion of the $price string and convert to float (float rather than integer because as others said, 1.2 is a float not an integer.  I recommend replacing '$' rather than splitting on it, in case a price has a number without the $.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['$68.95', '157.49']})
df3['price_as_number'] = df3['price'].str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
```

to get df3:

```
    price  price_as_number
0  $68.95            68.95
1  157.49           157.49
```

Comment: Excellent, could you accept my answer?